# How to create a custom Annotorious Widget using a Vue Component?

Tags: vuejs3, annotorious

I was able to adding the Annotorous (v2.7.11) into my ImageGallery Vuejs3 component. Also adding a custom widget as described [here](https://annotorious.github.io/guides/editor-widgets/) (and shown in the example below) was not a problem (apart from the parameter of type any, but that's not the question here). However, I would like to create a more complex widget and for that I would like to create the widget with a Vue component. The main problem I'm facing here is, that Annotorious is expecting the widget as a HTMLDivElement type and the Vue component obviously isn't of this type.

```
<template>
  <div id="my-annotation-toolbar-container"></div>
  <img id="image" v-bind:src="imageUrl" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Annotorious } from "@recogito/annotorious";
import "@recogito/annotorious/dist/annotorious.min.css";
import Toolbar from "@recogito/annotorious-toolbar";
import SelectorPack from "@recogito/annotorious-selector-pack";
import BetterPolygon from "@recogito/annotorious-better-polygon";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ImageGallery",
  props: {
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const anno = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      anno.value = new Annotorious({
        image: document.getElementById("image"),
        widgets: [colorSelectorWidget, "TAG"],
        formatter: colorFormatter,
      });
      SelectorPack(anno.value, { tools: ["multipolygon"] });
      Toolbar(
        anno.value,
        document.getElementById("my-annotation-toolbar-container")
      );
      BetterPolygon(anno.value);
    });

    const colorFormatter = (annotation: any) => {
      var highlightBody = annotation.bodies.find(function (b: any) {
        return b.purpose == "highlighting";
      });

      if (highlightBody) return highlightBody.value;
    };

    const colorSelectorWidget = (args: any) => {
      // 1. Find a current color setting in the annotation, if any
      var currentColorBody = args.annotation
        ? args.annotation.bodies.find(function (b: any) {
            return b.purpose == "highlighting";
          })
        : null;

      // 2. Keep the value in a variable
      var currentColorValue = currentColorBody ? currentColorBody.value : null;

      // 3. Triggers callbacks on user action
      var addTag = function (evt: any) {
        if (currentColorBody) {
          args.onUpdateBody(currentColorBody, {
            type: "TextualBody",
            purpose: "highlighting",
            value: evt.target.dataset.tag,
          });
        } else {
          args.onAppendBody({
            type: "TextualBody",
            purpose: "highlighting",
            value: evt.target.dataset.tag,
          });
        }
      };

      // 4. This part renders the UI elements
      var createButton = function (value: string) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");

        if (value == currentColorValue) button.className = "selected";

        button.dataset.tag = value;
        button.style.backgroundColor = value;
        button.addEventListener("click", addTag);
        return button;
      };

      var container = document.createElement("div");
      container.className = "colorselector-widget";

      var button1 = createButton("RED");
      var button2 = createButton("GREEN");
      var button3 = createButton("BLUE");

      container.appendChild(button1);
      container.appendChild(button2);
      container.appendChild(button3);

      return container;
    };

    return {};
  },
});
</script>

<style>
.colorselector-widget {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.colorselector-widget button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 4px;
}

.colorselector-widget button.selected,
.colorselector-widget button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.RED .a9s-outer {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.GREEN .a9s-outer {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}

svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.BLUE .a9s-outer {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}

svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.RED .a9s-inner,
svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.GREEN .a9s-inner,
svg.a9s-annotationlayer .a9s-annotation.BLUE .a9s-inner {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry for not having a better answer. But it's not possible to write a widget with Vue for the 2.x version of Annotorious. If you're up for some experimentation, you might be better off trying the upcoming v3. It's still in alpha state and has little documentation, but it's set up to be more framework agnostic. You could look into the code for the React binding as an example, and then follow a similar approach to build your own Vue-based popup. https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious-v3